# Javascript into PHP foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, foreach

I am trying to set a calendar of image button to enter the date into a textbox, that is generated by foreach loop. I used this code, but it only generated the calendar for the 1st box only (1st iteration of the loop). Any way to make it work for all iterations?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "../bulkmail/images.png",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "Select date"
    });
  });
</script>


echo '<table>';
foreach( $records as $key => $record){

     $Counter++;
    //start of row
    echo '<tr>'; 
    $ListName = $record->getField($fields[1]);
    $Priority = $record->getField($fields[2]);
    $TargetDate = $record->getField($fields[3]);
    $MailDate = $record->getField($fields[5]);

    $ListName_td = '<td class="LN">'.$ListName.'</td>';
    $Priority_td = '<td class="P">'.$Priority.'</td>';
    $TargetDate_td = '<td class="TD">'.$TargetDate.'</td>';
    $MailDate_td = '<td class="MD"><input type="text" id="datepicker" " name="MailDate'.$Counter.'"  value="'.$MailDate.'"/>
                                   </td>';

    echo '<tr>';}
    echo '<table>';
```

Comment: Im just wondering, what is the purpose of the `getField()` method ?

Comment: what are the contents of `$records` ?

Comment: where is the variable `$fields` defined?

Comment: you are missing a closing `</tr>` tag. You have `<tr>` instead.

Comment: I will vote to close this question, too many syntax errors. Fix that first, and maybe try giving us some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You used an id (`#datepicker`), but ids are supposed to be unique in the page. Use a class instead: `class="datepicker"` in your input and `$(".datepicker")` as your CSS selector in your JS.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "../bulkmail/images.png",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "Select date"
    });
  });
</script>


echo '<table>';
foreach( $records as $key => $record){

     $Counter++;
    //start of row
    echo '<tr>'; 
    $ListName = $record->getField($fields[1]);
    $Priority = $record->getField($fields[2]);
    $TargetDate = $record->getField($fields[3]);
    $MailDate = $record->getField($fields[5]);

    $ListName_td = '<td class="LN">'.$ListName.'</td>';
    $Priority_td = '<td class="P">'.$Priority.'</td>';
    $TargetDate_td = '<td class="TD">'.$TargetDate.'</td>';
    $MailDate_td = '<td class="MD"><input type="text" class="datepicker" " name="MailDate'.$Counter.'"  value="'.$MailDate.'"/>
                                   </td>';

    echo '<tr>';}
    echo '<table>';
```

Comment: Use class instead of id.